# Safari/webapp launching native application iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, native

I have a simple nginx docker container, ip => 192.168.99.100, which serves static html file with a bit of javascript in it. I mapped docker's port 80 to my machines, 172.20.16.34:8080, so I can access it from mobile device on local network.

I have a simple button with an 'click' event listener. On click this code is triggered:

```
window.location = "xyz_app://hello_world"
```

I expect this code to launch our native application on the device, with the registered URL scheme. However what always happens is that browser tries to redirect to:

```
172.20.16.34:8080/xyz_app://hello_world
```

instead of to:

```
xyz_app://hello_world
```

and opening the application. Any idea why?

When I was looking for ways of launching native applications from Safari, this:

```
window.location = "xyz_app://hello_world"
```

was the most commonly suggested way.

Comment: Does your URL scheme have an underscore in it?

Comment: Yes it does, is that a problem?

Comment: Yeah, URL schemes can't contain underscores in them.

Comment: Removing the underscore worked like a charm! Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Do you want me to post this as an answer so that the question is marked as solved?

Comment: I was thinking about that, yes I think you should, so I can give you credit you deserve as well... :)

Comment: Sure, I'll just post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your URL scheme does not have an underscore in it, as if it does it will not be correctly recognised as a URL scheme.